# Control two instances of Evince from one script

Tags: multiple-monitors, pdf, evince, presentation

I am looking for a way to synchronize two instances of Evince, so when one of them move a page up or down, the other one will do the same.  This is for running a dual-head PDF presentation, where once screen shows the presentation itself, and another the notes.  I suppose this involves monitoring dbus messages for one instance and sending dbus commands to the other one, but I couldn't find a detailed documentation of these options.  I'll appreciate pointers or ideas.  Also, if the same trick could be done by another PDF reader (acroread, xpdf, etc.), it also works for me.